# SVN hook script conflict

Tags: python, svn, conflict, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

I am trying to write a pre-commit hook script that will alter a specific svn-property of a folder/file.
The script looks fairly similar to the one that is documented in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.developer.usingapi.html).

I figured out how to set/change the property of a node and when executing the binding function svn.fs.commit_txn the property of the node actually gets set. 
But at the moment tortoise always gives me a conflict on the folder I am altering the property. I wrote my script with Python but am new python and hook scripts.

Hope someone can give me a clue why I am getting this conflict..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating a property on a directory you are required to update that directory before committing.

Answer (score 0):

You should never change data in a hook script. You lose the synchronization of the client and the subversion repository.

Comment: Okay I didn't know that but I will look for a different approach to solve my problem. Thanks for the advice!